# Incorrect output of quadratic equation

Tags: calculator, equation

I have a problem, and I don't know how to deal with it. I made a simple calculator with few functions. Every option is working fine, but I have problem when it comes to quadratic equation. When I put any numbers the response that I get is "The roots of the equations are : x=1.79599e-307. I don't know to deal with it - can you help me ? I will post parts of my code that includes the problem. Thanks You for any feedback and help!

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "kalkulator.cpp"
...
using namespace std;
case 10:
      cout<<"\nQuadratic Equation \n";
      cout<<"\nSelect number \n";
      cin>>a;
      cout<<"\nSelect number \n";
      cin>>b;
      cout<<"\nSelect bumber \n";
      cin>>c;
      int r;
      r=equation(a, b, c, x1, x2);
      if (r==0) cout << "\n No roots\n" << endl;
      else if (r==1) cout << "\n 1 root x = " << x1 << endl;
      else if (r==2) cout << "\n 2 roots x1 = " << x1 << " and x2 = " << x2 << endl;
      break;
```

kalkulator.cpp

```
#include "kalkulator.h"
using namespace std;
...
double equation(double a, double b, double c, double x1, double     
x2)
{
 double delta=b*b-4*a*c;
 if (delta<0.0)
{
return 0;}
if (delta==0.0)
{
x1=-b/(2*a);
return 1;}
else
{
delta=sqrt(delta);
x1==(-b-delta)/(2*a);
x2==(-b+delta)/(2*a);
return 2;}}
```

kalkulator.h

```
#ifndef kalkulator_H
#define kalkulator_H

class kalkulator
{
private:
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  double x1;
  double x2;
public:
  double equation(double, double, double, double, double);
};
#endif
```

Comment: Read about references. `x1` and `x2` are passed by value, so you don't change the original variables. Also, please format your code better in the future - otherwise most people will just ignore it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set x1 and x2 through the supplied parameters, you need to pass them by reference:

```
  double equation(double, double, double, double&, double&);
```

and

```
double equation(double a, double b, double c, double & x1, double & x2)
```

Also, in the last lines of your code, "x1==" and "x2==" should be "x1=" and "x2=".